# Application class returns null after capturing image android

Tags: android

I have an activity A and activity B. In activity A, I am saving some data in application class and then going to activity B.

In Activity B, I am able to access data which I saved in application class when I am coming from activity A ,

There is a button in activity B to capture image. When I capture the image and return to Activity B after capturing , application class returns null and I am not able to fetch data again.

Application Class Code:

```
 public void saveSelectedSalonDetail(SalonDetailsModel salonDetail){
        this.salonDetails = salonDetail;
    }
    public SalonDetailsModel getSalonDetails(){
        Log.e("salon details ",this.salonDetails.getBusinessName());
        return salonDetails;
    }
```

Activity A Code:- To Save data in application class

```
  ((AppController) getApplicationContext()).saveSelectedSalonDetail(salonDetailsModel);
```

Activity B Code:-

```
AppController appController = (AppController)getApplication();
SalonDetailsModel salonDetailsModel  = appController.getSalonDetails();
String salonTitle = salonDetailsModel.getBusinessName();
```

The above line returns the value when i am coming from activity A but when i come to activity b after capturing picture , same line returns null.

Comment: share the stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

> There is a button in activity B to capture image. When I capture the image and return to Activity B after capturing , application class returns null and I am not able to fetch data again.

I assume that you are using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` to capture the image. In this case, your behavior is perfectly normal.

Any time your application does not have an activity in the foreground, your app's process can be terminated. This includes when the camera app is in the foreground.

Storing data in `static` fields or in `Application` subclasses is OK, so long as you do not leak memory and **so long as you are only using this for a cache**. If you have data that needs to survive your process being terminated, you need to have a plan for storing that data outside of your process (e.g., database, preferences, other sort of file, the Internet).